# fail2ban PostgreSQL Filter not working

Tags: postgresql, fail2ban

I use this filter for postgresql:

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST>.+FATAL:  password authentication failed for user.+$
            ^<HOST>.+FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host .+$
ignoreregex = duration:#
```

In my jail file I have the fowlling configuration:

```
[postgresql]
enabled = true
port    = 5432
protocol = tcp
filter = custom-postgresql
logpath = /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
maxretry = 3
```

In my postgresql.conf I change the log information:

```
log_line_prefix = '%h %m [%p] %q%u@%d '
```

But when I try to test it with failban I get these errors:

```
root@server:/etc/fail2ban# fail2ban-regex /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/custom-postgresql.conf /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log

Running tests
=============

Use   failregex file : /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
Wrong config file: File contains no section headers.
file: '/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log', line: 1
'2020-08-30 01:19:48.411 CEST [28837] [unknown]@[unknown] FATAL:  unsupported frontend protocol 0.0: server supports 2.0 to 3.0\n'
ERROR: failed to load filter /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
```

What is my error here? What did I miss?

Could it be an error from postgresql? Because in the logs I see this:

```
2020-08-30 01:19:48.411 CEST [28837] [unknown]@[unknown] FATAL:  unsupported frontend protocol 0.0: server supports 2.0 to 3.0
2020-08-30 01:19:48.619 CEST [28838] [unknown]@[unknown] FATAL:  unsupported frontend protocol 255.255: server supports 2.0 to 3.0
2020-08-30 01:19:48.828 CEST [28839] [unknown]@[unknown] FATAL:  no PostgreSQL user name specified in startup packet
2020-08-30 02:20:12.462 CEST [29766] [unknown]@[unknown] FATAL:  unsupported frontend protocol 65363.19778: server supports 2.0 to 3.0
2020-08-30 03:16:01.172 CEST [31372] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2020-08-30 03:16:01.189 CEST [31373] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2020-08-30 03:16:01.205 CEST [31374] [unknown]@[unknown] FATAL:  unsupported frontend protocol 65363.19778: server supports 2.0 to 3.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are providing the parameters in the wrong order.

From `man fail2ban-regex`:

```
fail2ban-regex [OPTIONS] <LOG> <REGEX> [IGNOREREGEX]
```

You must provide first the log file and then the configuration file, you are doing it the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST>.*FATAL:\s\spassword authentication failed for user
            ^<HOST>.*FATAL:\s\sno pg_hba.conf entry for host
ignoreregex =
```